# TeleUSE window not resizing

Tags: c, user-interface

We're porting an application from Tru64 to SLES11 and the part that I'm working on right now is a GUI written with TeleUSE.
The problem that I'm encountering is that one of my XmBulletinBoardDialogs has only half the size on LINUX compared to Tru64. I've tried to change the height in the pcd file and the generated c code looks alright but has no effect:

`XtSetArg(args[n], XmNheight, 800); n++;`

Any appearance changes that I've tried had no effect also..
Are there known problems or changes in functionality between the platforms or should I search for constraints from parent windows (then how would they look like?)? I'm new to TeleUSE so any hint on a probable source for the problem would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the window was set by the input string "\n\n\n\n TEXT \n\n\n"
The problem was that apparently the parsing of the string is working differently with the function "XmStringCreateLtoR". I had to add spaces between the \n's for the line breaks to have an effect